# C# Running 3 MYSQL insert queries with single button press - Data from textboxes and listview

Tags: c#, mysql, listview, last-insert-id

I was wondering if you can help me. Firstly I wanted to say that this is my first application in C# that I am created so please accept that my code is not perfect.

What I want to achieve: 
My application will be a Car Repair Management App. I have a panel on which I have few texboxes and a list. With a single button click I want to make it so that data in text boxes will be stored in table called 'naprawa' and data from list to be stored in table called 'opisynapraw'. These tables are related with FK from 'naprawa' so I want that items from list when they are stored they will have FK of just created field in other table. (If that makes sense)

Please see table setup below: 
Naprawa

```
|--------------+----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type           | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
|--------------+----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Nr_Naprawy   | int(11)        | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| data_naprawy | date           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| nr_rej       | varchar(45)    | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| Przebieg     | int(15)        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
|--------------+----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Data in that table:

```
|------------+--------------+---------+-----------|
| Nr_Naprawy | data_naprawy | nr_rej  | Przebieg  |
|------------+--------------+---------+-----------|
|      1     |  2018-06-20  | na06ysa |   150000  |
|------------+--------------+---------+-----------|
```

Table opisynapraw:

```
+---------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| idopisynapraw | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| Opis_Naprawy  | varchar(45)   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Cena          | decimal(10,2) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Nr_Naprawy    | int(11)       | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+---------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Example Data that I would like to see in that table:

```
|---------------+--------------+-------+-------------|
| idopisynapraw | Opis_Naprawy | Cena  | Nr_Naprawy  |
|---------------+--------------+-------+-------------|
|       1       |  notes abcd  |  30   |      1      |
|---------------+--------------+-------+-------------|
|       2       |  notes cdef  |   5   |      1      |
|---------------+--------------+-------+-------------|
```

What I want my code to do. I when I press Add button it will add the record from text boxes into 'naprawa'. Then take the ID of what was added and use it as FK for opisynapraw and add it along with data from listveiw to opisynapraw table.

Here is my code.

```
private void btnDodajNaprawe_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                MySqlConnection myConn3 = new MySqlConnection(MyConnection);

                myConn3.Open();



                string querydoajnap = "INSERT INTO naprawa (data_naprawy,nr_rej,Przebieg) VALUES('" + dtaData.Value.Date.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd") + "', '" + txtNrRej.Text + "', '" + txtPrzebieg.Text + "');";
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(querydoajnap, myConn3);

                MySqlConnection lastidconn = new MySqlConnection(MyConnection);
                lastidconn.Open();


                if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Dodane");


                    txtNrRej.Text = string.Empty;
                    txtPrzebieg.Text = string.Empty;

                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Blad");
                }




                String LastIDnapr = "select LAST_INSERT_ID();";
                MySqlCommand cmd1 = new MySqlCommand(LastIDnapr, lastidconn);
                MySqlDataReader IDRead = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
                int idnumber = 0;
                while (IDRead.Read())
                {
                    idnumber = IDRead.GetInt32(0);
                }

                MySqlCommand cmd2 = myConn3.CreateCommand();

                foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.Items)
                {
                    // opisynapraw(Opis_Naprawy,Cena,Nr_Naprawy) VALUES (@val1 , @val2, '" + idnumber + "');";


                    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val1",item.Text);
                    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val2",item.SubItems[1].Text);
                    cmd2.CommandText = "INSERT INTO opisynapraw(Opis_Naprawy,Cena,Nr_Naprawy) VALUES (@val1 , @val2, '" + idnumber + "');";
                    cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                lastidconn.Close();
                myConn3.Close();


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

When I execute the above code it works for adding data to table 'Naprawa' but I think it will not take last used ID to relate to 'opisynapraw' table what brings following error.

For some reason I need some rep points to post images... I will type below what error message I'm having

> Cannot add or update a child row; a foreign key contraint fails
>   ('cars','opisynapraw', CONSTRAINT 'Nr_Naprawy'FOREIGN Key
>   ('Nr_Naprawy') REFERENCES 'naprawa'('Nr_Naprawy') ON DELETE NO ACTION
>   ON UPDATE NO ACTION)

I would very appreciate any help in resolving this mystery.

Thank You in advance

Rogupl

Comment: The Visual Studio tag clearly states: *"DO NOT use this tag on questions regarding code which merely happened to be written in Visual Studio"*, so I'll remove that from your question. There is also something wrong in the `foreach` loop so I'll comment out the bit causing the problem... Please check my edit and fix it if it's not right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the `INSERT` into Naprawa to give you back the auto generated value in the same query. Add this into the end of your insert statement, after the `;`

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

Then to get it back, change the `ExecuteNonQuery` into `ExecuteScalar` - the value it returns will be the value you need - it returns it as an object, so either cast it or `System.Convert` it. (This requires you to remove your check that it inserted 1 row; but bear in mind it will throw an exception of it fails.)

Now remove the code relating to the `LastIDnapr` query, it should work fine.

Additional tips:

1. Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks: use SQL parameters rather than string concatenation to construct a query.
2. MySqlConnection, MySqlCommand, and MySqlDataReader are all IDisposable so each should be in a `using` block.
3. Those connections are connecting to the same database so ensure that they don't overlap. This will be obvious once you're using `using` blocks.
4. Take a look at [can we stop using AddWithValue](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: Hi! Thank you very much for your answer !! I have managed to tweak the code to insert the record from list view into 'opisynapraw' with correct FK. ! I unfortunately have some problem with FOREACH Loop as when I have multiple records it says "Parameter @Val1 has already been defined"

Comment: Also Thank you very much for additional Tips!!. I will be taking these on board and I will be tiding up the code once I have all functionality that I need. !!

Comment: I would suggest making each database call independent. So have one method which inserts the parent and returns the auto generated value, and another which inserts a single child record. Each of the MySqlConnections and MySqlCommands etc should all be pushed into the relevant one of those 2 methods. This will give you a better *separation of concerns*, keeping the data storage logic away from  the logic of what you want to store. This way, each call to store the child record is independent, so your problem will go away. Or the cheap and nasty fix is to just `cmd2.Parameters.Clear();`.

Comment: Thank you again! That has solved my problem. Like I said I will be tiding up the code later on as I am aware of good few flaws with my system.  I wish I could give you a rep point but I think I need to have 15 myself to give one.

Answer (score 0):

You should always use SqlCommand and it's Parameters due to dangerous of sql injection code.
Also, a good idea is to make a database handler class, which will handle all these things.

But let's come back to your problem, I strongly believe you're trying to insert id to table opisynapraw, that doesn't exist in table naprawa as id. Please check what id you're  getting, what you're trying to insert and verify it with database data.